# best method of making a tweet-this button?

Tags: html, twitter

It looks like there's lots of different sites/methods for doing this,

is there an official twitter share button?

like for facebook there's http://developers.facebook.com/tools.php?connect_wizard&wizard=stream_publish , which looks excellent

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the button below and use one of many free social networking icons:

```
<a expr:href='"http://twitter.com/home?status=Reading " + data:post.title + " @YOURTwitterUSERNAME " + data:post.url' title='Tweet this article on Twitter' target='_blank'><img src='yourTwitterButtonURL'/></a>
```

Comment: thanks kasia,
dont suppose you've got any links to any good icons?

also is there any way to edit the default text (like my facebook example)

Comment: Why do you use `expr:` before `href`? Which server side language is that?

Comment: @Haroldo: Google is your friend: http://www.google.com/search?q=free+twitter+icon

Comment: yep i did google first but wanted a few opinions as to 'the best' one to go for.
i didn't come across john resig's script in google! thanks again Confusion!

Comment: @Haroldo: "The best one" (if you mean the best icon) is a matter of taste, of course.